# Getting error ERC20: insufficient allowance even after the user approving the tokens. Need help with debugging

Tags: solidity, erc-20, foundry, erc-20-approve, stablecoins

The following code is from a Stablecoin project.

To gain more context, please refer to [this Github repo](https://github.com/alfheimrShiven/defi-stablecoin).

I've added a new function to the DSCEngine.sol name collapseDsc() which is responsible for returning the collateral deposited by all users of the protocol, in case of a dramatic collapse of the underlying asset (wEth, wBtc) values.

**DSCEngine.sol**

```
function collapseDsc() public {
       
        uint256 totalCollateralValueOfProtocol = _getTotalCollateralValueOfProtocol();
        uint256 totalDSCMinted = i_dsc.totalSupply();

        
        if(totalCollateralValueOfProtocol > totalDSCMinted) {
            revert DSCEngine__DSCNotCollapsed(totalDSCMinted, totalCollateralValueOfProtocol);
        }

        emit DSCProtocolCollapsed();
        console.log('Users in the protocol: ', s_users.length);
        
        for(uint256 u = 0; u < s_users.length; u++){
            address user = s_users[u];
            uint256 userDscMinted = s_DSCMinted[user];
            
            if(userDscMinted > 0) {
                _burnDSC(userDscMinted, user);
            }
            
            for(uint256 t = 0 ; t < s_collateralTokens.length; t++) {
                address collateralToken = s_collateralTokens[t];
                uint256 collateralTokenAmount = s_collateralDeposited[user][collateralToken];

                if(collateralTokenAmount > 0 ) {
                    _redeemCollateral(collateralToken, collateralTokenAmount, user, user);
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
```

I have the following Fuzz tests:

Minting DSC: This will mint the DSC and approve it to the DSCEngine at the same time.

**Handler.t.sol**

```
 function mintDsc(uint256 mintAmount, uint256 userWithCollateralSeed) public {
        if(usersWithDepositedCollateral.length == 0){
            return;
        } 
        // Arrange
        address sender = _getRandomUserWithCollateral(userWithCollateralSeed); 
        
        // mintAmount should not be 0 and should not be more than (half the collateral value deposited - dscMinted)
        (uint256 dscMinted, uint256 collateralDepositedValue) = dscEngine
            .getAccountInformation(sender);

        int256 maxMintAmount = (int256(collateralDepositedValue) / 2) - int256(dscMinted);
        if (maxMintAmount < 0) {
            // this can happen if the collateral value drops after a token crash
            return;
        }

        mintAmount = bound(mintAmount, 0, uint256(maxMintAmount));
        if (mintAmount == 0) {
            // can be 0 if no collateral is deposited
            return;
        }

        vm.startPrank(sender);
        dscEngine.mintDSC(mintAmount);
        dsc.approve(address(dscEngine), mintAmount); // dsc approval given to dscEngine by the user, incase burning of these tokens required. 
        vm.stopPrank();
        mintDscCalls++;
    }
```

The second is the test which crashes the value of the underlying asset and triggers the `collapseDsc()` function.

**Handler.t.sol**

```
 // TODO This breaks our system and should be taken care of.
    function updateEthUsdPriceFeed(uint96 newEthUsdPrice) public {
        
        // Arrange
        MockV3Aggregator ethUsdPriceFeed = MockV3Aggregator(dscEngine.getCollateralTokenPriceFeed(wEth));
        int256 newPrice = int256(uint256(newEthUsdPrice));
        ethUsdPriceFeed.updateAnswer(newPrice);
        

        uint256 totalDscMinted = dsc.totalSupply();
        uint256 wEthDeposited = ERC20Mock(wEth).balanceOf(address(dscEngine));
        uint256 wBtcDeposited = ERC20Mock(wBtc).balanceOf(address(dscEngine));

        uint256 totalCollateralValue = dscEngine.getUsdValue(wEth, wEthDeposited) + dscEngine.getUsdValue(wBtc, wBtcDeposited);

        // Act
        if(totalCollateralValue < totalDscMinted){
            dscEngine.collapseDsc();
        }
    }
```

Now on running this test, I get a revert. Here are the error logs:

```
[234902] Handler::updateEthUsdPriceFeed(4463) 
    ├─ [2613] DSCEngine::getCollateralTokenPriceFeed(ERC20Mock: [0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← MockV3Aggregator: [0xA8452Ec99ce0C64f20701dB7dD3abDb607c00496]
    ├─ [79404] MockV3Aggregator::updateAnswer(4463) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [2349] DecentralizedStableCoin::totalSupply() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 36867680678869884643073056819756867246485946828 [3.686e46]
    ├─ [2585] ERC20Mock::balanceOf(DSCEngine: [0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 147181787746094153296977941449 [1.471e29]
    ├─ [2585] ERC20Mock::balanceOf(DSCEngine: [0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 118501289238336304 [1.185e17]
    ├─ [18666] DSCEngine::getUsdValue(ERC20Mock: [0x50EEf481cae4250d252Ae577A09bF514f224C6C4], 118501289238336304 [1.185e17]) [staticcall]
    │   ├─ [12650] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000bb2180ebd78ce97360503434ed37fcf4a1df61c3) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [8993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 1, 100000000000, 1, 1, 1
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000174876e800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    │   └─ ← 118501289238336304000 [1.185e20]
    ├─ [3666] DSCEngine::getUsdValue(ERC20Mock: [0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76], 147181787746094153296977941449 [1.471e29]) [staticcall]
    │   ├─ [2150] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000a8452ec99ce0c64f20701db7dd3abdb607c00496) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 6, 4463, 1, 1, 6
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000116f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
    │   └─ ← 6568723187108182061644125 [6.568e24]
    ├─ [92888] DSCEngine::collapseDsc() 
    │   ├─ [2150] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000a8452ec99ce0c64f20701db7dd3abdb607c00496) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 6, 4463, 1, 1, 6
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000116f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
    │   ├─ [2150] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000bb2180ebd78ce97360503434ed37fcf4a1df61c3) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 1, 100000000000, 1, 1, 1
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000174876e800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    │   ├─ [2150] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000a8452ec99ce0c64f20701db7dd3abdb607c00496) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 6, 4463, 1, 1, 6
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000116f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
    │   ├─ [2150] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000bb2180ebd78ce97360503434ed37fcf4a1df61c3) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 1, 100000000000, 1, 1, 1
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000174876e800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    │   ├─ [2150] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000a8452ec99ce0c64f20701db7dd3abdb607c00496) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 6, 4463, 1, 1, 6
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000116f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
    │   ├─ [2150] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000bb2180ebd78ce97360503434ed37fcf4a1df61c3) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 1, 100000000000, 1, 1, 1
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000174876e800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    │   ├─ [2150] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000a8452ec99ce0c64f20701db7dd3abdb607c00496) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 6, 4463, 1, 1, 6
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000116f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
    │   ├─ [2150] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000bb2180ebd78ce97360503434ed37fcf4a1df61c3) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 1, 100000000000, 1, 1, 1
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000174876e800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    │   ├─ [2150] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000a8452ec99ce0c64f20701db7dd3abdb607c00496) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 6, 4463, 1, 1, 6
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000116f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
    │   ├─ [2150] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000bb2180ebd78ce97360503434ed37fcf4a1df61c3) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 1, 100000000000, 1, 1, 1
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000174876e800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    │   ├─ [349] DecentralizedStableCoin::totalSupply() [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← 36867680678869884643073056819756867246485946828 [3.686e46]
    │   ├─ emit DSCProtocolCollapsed()
    │   ├─ [0] console::9710a9d0(000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017557365727320696e207468652070726f746f636f6c3a20000000000000000000) [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   ├─ [3016] DecentralizedStableCoin::transferFrom(0x8499B29da102AD9F9C76c0380A190408a49e2326, DSCEngine: [0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512], 59250644619166520499 [5.925e19]) 
    │   │   └─ ← "ERC20: insufficient allowance"
    │   └─ ← "ERC20: insufficient allowance"
    └─ ← "ERC20: insufficient allowance"

  [75427] InvariantsTest::invariant_protocolMustAlwaysHaveMoreCollateralValueThanMintedDSCValue() 
    ├─ [2349] DecentralizedStableCoin::totalSupply() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 36867680678869884643073056819756867246485946828 [3.686e46]
    ├─ [2585] ERC20Mock::balanceOf(DSCEngine: [0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 147181787746094153296977941449 [1.471e29]
    ├─ [2585] ERC20Mock::balanceOf(DSCEngine: [0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 118501289238336304 [1.185e17]
    ├─ [18666] DSCEngine::getUsdValue(ERC20Mock: [0x50EEf481cae4250d252Ae577A09bF514f224C6C4], 118501289238336304 [1.185e17]) [staticcall]
    │   ├─ [12650] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000bb2180ebd78ce97360503434ed37fcf4a1df61c3) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [8993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 1, 100000000000, 1, 1, 1
    │   │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000174876e800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    │   └─ ← 118501289238336304000 [1.185e20]
    ├─ [16166] DSCEngine::getUsdValue(ERC20Mock: [0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76], 147181787746094153296977941449 [1.471e29]) [staticcall]
    │   ├─ [12650] OracleLib::2ba1c96a(000000000000000000000000a8452ec99ce0c64f20701db7dd3abdb607c00496) [delegatecall]
    │   │   ├─ [8993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 5, 93067110251944013583873118, 1, 1, 5
    │   │   └─ ← 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000000000004cfbba27f6840d86cbf45e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
    │   └─ ← 136977836672439669664473841260116313382165854880 [1.369e47]
    ├─ [0] console::9710a9d0(000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000006753437ea323983eb5b8b193a9445be01d841cc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012546f74616c2044534320537570706c793a200000000000000000000000000000) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] console::9710a9d0(000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000017fe4c72fda38f95a91c31d6fd5a12f4a5a9ae200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018546f74616c20436f6c6c61746572616c2076616c75653a200000000000000000) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [2308] Handler::mintDscCalls() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 3
    ├─ [0] console::9710a9d0(00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c4d696e742063616c6c733a200000000000000000000000000000000000000000) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    └─ ← ()
```

I don't understand why I'm getting a `ERC20: insufficient allowance` error when the user is allowing the DSCEngine the DSCs they mint, right after the minting in the `mintDsc(..)` test.

**Source code:** https://github.com/alfheimrShiven/defi-stablecoin

**Github discussion thread:** https://github.com/Cyfrin/foundry-full-course-f23/discussions/871#discussioncomment-7012541

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was due to the assumption that the `approve(...)` function adds up the allowance approved to the spender, in case called multiple times, **but that isn't the case.** **Only the latest `mintAmount` allowance holds true**, not the cumulative value!
Hence instead of giving the allowance each time the DSC is minted, I have written a modifier that should give the allowance to **all DSC minted by the user at once.**

[Refer this commit](https://github.com/alfheimrShiven/defi-stablecoin/commit/25547812e3bc3d1ce9b6c28e591c10b3272909e9)